# error found with working with text files in python

Tags: python

I'm making a small game for school, and in order for users to play, they need to validate themselves using a username and password. The code for validation I wrote executes nothing however I cannot find what I have done incorrectly.

```
usernamevalidation = input("Enter your username\n")
passwordvalidation = input("Enter your password")
opener = open("validationneaparta.txt","r")
reader = opener.readline()
splitting = reader.split(":")
print(splitting[1])
if usernamevalidation == splitting[1]:
  print("test")
```

The text file:

```
username:dallavid
password:nea2020
```

Comment: You haven't said what the actual issue is. What is the error?

Comment: @roganjosh It executes nothing.

Comment: @roganjosh I guess he meant the output returns `nothing` means his `if` condition fails

Comment: It can't execute nothing unless it's in a function that you haven't shown. It's really important to be specific about errors with code because it can come down to a missing colon or something. It almost certainly _does_ execute code, and "executing nothing" is not an _error_

Comment: @roganjosh the if statement executes nothing, it should execute "test" so that i can tell that the if statement is working

Comment: Do `print(repr(splitting[1]))` to see why the if condition fails.

Comment: Ok, but that's not an error. What does it do if you put an `else` in and `print(splitting[1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have trim check the data for any unwanted spaces. Below code works for me.

```
if usernamevalidation == splitting[1].strip():
  print("test")
```